# SD card does not mount in Broadcom BCM57765/57785 (Macbook pro) card reader

Tags: kernel, mount, sd-card

I have a micro SD card, SanDisk Ultra 16 GB, Ultra High Speed, formatted FAT, in a SD adapter and a Macbook pro 8,1 running Ubuntu 20.10.

- The SD card does not work in the internal SD card reader: it appears as 16 GB unknown in Disks.
- The same SD card works through a USB external card reader.
- It also works in the same internal card reader of the same Mac after rebooting with Mac OS.

As the card and the reader work, I suspect that Ubuntu misses something.

After reformatting (FAT again), the card seems to work (seen as 16 GB FAT in Disks) but when trying to copy a file to it by drag and drop from the desktop, the cursor arrow becomes a hand and Ubuntu freezes.  I can recover by restarting but thereafter the SD card is seen as before in Disks: 16 GB unknown.

I tried another card SDXC 128 GB ExFAT, with the same results (except maybe for reformatting that I did not try because I have useful data on the card).

Any suggestion to obtain normal function of the internal SD card reader with Ubuntu?

### Update

(After mook765's comment.)

When the SD card is inserted in Macbook pro internal SD card reader, it almost never mounts, appearing as unknown in Disks.  `dmesg` output:

```
[29944.127784] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address e624
[29944.129766] mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SC16G 14.8 GiB 
[29954.151831] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[29954.151847] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[29954.151927] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x000010c8 | Version:  0x00001502
[29954.151940] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[29954.151976] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[29954.151981] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0000 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
[29954.151987] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[29954.151992] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[29954.151998] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[29954.152004] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
[29954.152009] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[29954.152014] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
[29954.152019] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00000000
[29954.152023] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
[29954.152028] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[29954.152031] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000804b
[29954.152037] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000045bfcd204
[29954.152039] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[29954.152111] mmc0: Unexpected interrupt 0x04000000.
[29954.152112] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[29954.152118] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001502
[29954.152123] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[29954.152129] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
[29954.152135] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0001 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
[29954.152141] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[29954.152146] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[29954.152151] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[29954.152156] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
[29954.152161] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[29954.152167] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
[29954.152172] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000c1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
[29954.152177] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
[29954.152182] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[29954.152185] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[29954.152192] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000045bfcd204
[29954.152193] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[29960.352164] mmc0: card e624 removed
```

`dmesg` output when mount succeeds:

```
[  104.086813] mmc0: Skipping voltage switch
[  105.010489] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address e624
[  105.011082] mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SC16G 14.8 GiB 
[  139.106588]  mmcblk0:
```

Note the correlation:

- ultra high speed -> failure,
- high speed -> success.

Manual mount attempt:

```
% sudo mount -v -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt             
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Nevertheless, Disks benchmark works. Average read rate 50 MB/s (limited by internal USB 2), average write rate 1 MB/s (that is poor performance of Apple hardware).

Formatting in Disks often fails with

```
Error formatting volume Error after formatting with type vfat: Timed-out waiting for object (udisk-error-quark 0)
```

Manual formatting may work:

```
% sudo mkfs.vfat -v -F 32 -n LUMIX -I /dev/mmcblk0
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
attribute "partition" not found
/dev/mmcblk0 has 4 heads and 16 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 31116288 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 16 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 15184 sectors, and provides 1942868 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 01436e04, volume label LUMIX      .
```

The SD card mounts automatically once upon a time.  I have had at least 30 successive failures.  Success often occurs right after reformatting.

Once the card has been mounted and remains inserted, remount always succeeds.

The internal SD card reader may be defective.  As the same hardware works perfectly with Mac OS, I imagine that Apple has found a workaround, that Ubuntu ignores.

Properties of the internal SD card reader:

```
% sudo lspci -s 02:00.1 -v    
02:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 10) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a0420000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

% /sbin/modinfo sdhci-pci
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-pci.
ko
license:        GPL
description:    Secure Digital Host Controller Interface PCI driver
author:         Pierre Ossman <pierre@ossman.eu>

% uname -a
Linux mac2011-linux 5.8.0-31-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:44:54 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had other SD card problems a few weeks ago, before November 23, and I did not notice the present problem, so I bet that sdhci was touched in the last kernel revision.

Comment: exFAT isn't supported out of the box.  You need to install two packages:  sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils

Comment: I have them installed and the ExFAT card is read through external card reader.

Comment: After all those restarts I have now kernel panic.

Comment: I reset the NVRAM and entered a dialog asking to run fsck manually, which I did and I can boot normally again.

Comment: Formatting SD card fails with "Error formatting volume Error after formatting with type vfat: Timed-out waiting for object (udisk-error-quark 0)".

Comment: Same thing after reformatting with SD Card formatter version 5.0.1 on Mac OS (the recommended formatting tool of the SD association).  Card still usable through external reader.

Comment: After repairing this kernel panic and a number of strange reboots, the card seems to work again.

Comment: And now it is broken again.  In the internal card reader  must be some random failure that Mac OS is able to cope with but not Ubuntu.

Comment: SD cards do go bad after awhile, but I'd expect consistency with problems.  The F3 utility package will have test read/write programs to detect fraudulent cards (usually 8G marked as larger).  Those cards cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: This card works perfectly through external card reader or under Mac OS and 2 other cards have the same problems.

Comment: Again I had boot problem /dev/sda4: recovering journal /dev/sda4: clean Failed to start Network Name Resolution and recovered with manual fsck.  I don't know if the boot problem and the SD card reader problem are related.

Comment: Trying a fourth card that is a Raspberry Pi card, once it mounts, then it does not.  The problem is slightly random.   Sometimes a card will mount,  With Mac OS and the same hardware no problem.

Comment: Instead of posting hundrets of comments, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297047/edit) your question to include relevant information.

Answer (score 5):

The internal card reader indeed has a defect: it does not always recognize ultra high speed but this defect has a positive side effect: to allow mount as high speed.

The SD card can be mounted as high speed always instead of ultra high speed as follows:

```
% sudo rmmod sdhci_pci sdhci
% sudo modprobe sdhci debug_quirks2=4
% sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

(This change is not permanent.)

Disks benchmark results:

- read: 24 MB/s,
- write: 9 MB/s.

Read is worse than ultra high speed but fortunately write is much faster!  Having both read 50 MB/s and write 10 MB/s would be great.

[Similar report on Debian](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1801.1/04076.html)

[Proposed solution](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org&q=subject:%22Bug%23830303%5C%3A%20mmc0%5C%3A%20Unexpected%20interrupt%200x04000000.%22&o=newest&f=1)

> The problem can be resolved by passing `debug_quirks2=0x4` to sdhci kernel module.

[A known bug in Linux kernel](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73241#c55)

Comment: Works for the integrated SD card reader of my Apple Mac Mini 2014!

Comment: Doesn't work on 20.04 with realtek cad-reader. `mmc0: tuning execution failed: -22`

Comment: I also found I need the wifi turned on for it to not timeout (yes how weird).  Confirmed in the kernel discussion link https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73241#c62

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following to /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf:

  options sdhci debug_quirks2=4

Re-generate initrd:

 sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Reboot or reload sdhci module:

 sudo rmmod sdhci-pci sdhci
 sudo modprobe sdhci
```