# Ubuntu won't read SD cards on a 2012 MacBook Air

Tags: 20.04, macbook, sd-card

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) on a 2012 MacBook Air, and having my second Ubuntu computer, I was happy. But then, suddenly I found, that the card reader on the right side, is not working. How do I fix this? Is this a driver problem, or a broken cheap SD Card reader?
I will be very thankful for you answer.

Here's the output of `lsusb` :

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:8404 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:024c Apple, Inc. 

Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05ac:821f Apple, Inc. Built-in Bluetooth 2.0+EDR HCI

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 2.0 Hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8510 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: That may be a classical problem, see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297047/sd-card-does-not-mount-in-broadcom-bcm57765-57785-macbook-pro-card-reader/1297319#1297319

Comment: What do you see in Disks?

Comment: and check also this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168065/is-it-possible-to-override-the-sd-card-write-protection-setting-in-software/405874?noredirect=1#comment569556_405874

Comment: I see nothing in disks, @PierreALBARÈDE

Comment: It is a plain SD card from a Canon camera. It is visible when I am using an external card reader though.

Comment: If you see nothing new is Disks (`gnome-disks`) when you insert this card, then the card reader is dead.  You have to check.

Comment: I see this: https://ibb.co/xgQtQXP

Comment: I think it something wrong with the SD itself, @PierreALBARÈDE. I tried another one and it worked fine.

Comment: You see "No media" as if the card was not inserted.  Try many times to make sure.  Maybe clean the card and the reader with air jet.